# for ... in statement after if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm kind of new to js/ts, and recently saw some code that looked like this:

```
if (m.attributes) for (const aName in m.attributes) {
...
    }
```

I expect the `if` validates that `m.attributes` is not falsey (i.e. it's not null | undefined), and then the `for` statement essentially [loops over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) `m.attributes`.

Can someone please explain why the `for` statement is not in it's own scope?
I'd expect the syntax to look more like this:

```
if (m.attributes){
 for (const aName in m.attributes) {
  ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: If there's only one statement after an `if` the `{ }` are not necessary.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else Checkout the first section they show examples of single statements, then go on to describe how to execute multiple statements. Typescript follows the same syntax as Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly braces are redundant if there is only one statement after the `if` statement. With that said, this:

```
if (m.attributes) for (const aName in m.attributes) {
     ...
    }
```

although perfectly valid, is not a well-written piece of code. Typically, for added readability, one would write it like so:

```
if (m.attributes)
   for (const aName in m.attributes) {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: Personally, I would add the redundant curly braces, just for the sake of readability.

Comment: I would doubtless do the same. I was simply pointing out that if one has to go braceless, it would make for a more readable code to add a new line after the `if` statement.